# Replace specific string from two strings

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace a particular string from two strings. I want to remove `<br />` between `<blockquote>` and `</blockquote>` and then replace `<blockquote>` with `<pre>` and `</blockquote>` with `</pre>`

```
<blockquote>
data.frame()<br />
mutate()<br /></blockquote>
```

Final Result should look like below -

```
<pre>
data.frame()
mutate()
</pre>
```

I tried the following solution but it selects everything between blockquotes.

```
(?s)^\t*<blockquote>(.|\r\n)*?</blockquote>
```

Comment: What did you try and in which way did get stuck?

Comment: Thanks. I posted what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A.*?(?:<blockquote>|\G(?!<))(?:(?!</blockquote>).)*?\K<br />`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A                      # beginning of string
.*?                     # 0 or more any character, not greedy
(?:                     # start non capture group
  <blockquote>          # literally open tag
 |                      # OR
  \G                    # restart from last match position
  (?!<)                 # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't "<" after
)                       # end group
(?:                     # start non capture group
  (?!</blockquote>)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't after a closing tag
  .                     # any character
)*?                     # end group, may appear 0 or more times, not greedy
\K                      # forget all we have seen until this position
<br />                  # literally
```

**Given:**

```
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
<blockquote>
data.frame()<br />
mutate()<br /></blockquote>
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
<blockquote>
data.frame()<br />
mutate()<br /></blockquote>
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
```

**Result for given example:**

```
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
<blockquote>
data.frame()
mutate()</blockquote>
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
<blockquote>
data.frame()
mutate()</blockquote>
<tag>
blah<br />
blah<br />
</tag>
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. Well appreciated! I guess "UNcheck Match case" should be "check Match case"

Comment: @UjjawalBhandari: You're welcome. Check or UNcheck according to your needs, do you want to match `blockquote` as well as `BLOCKQUOTE` or not?

Comment: my bad. I was blindly following your snapshot and the option was checked. Thanks again!